# How to change extension of file before download it

Tags: android, pdf

I am using `Download Manager` class to download a pdf in webview from a website but the pdf is downloading as `filename.aspx`. How to convert it to `.aspx` to `.pdf`. Simply i want to save file as `filename.pdf` instead of `filename.aspx`

**Here is Code**

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setTitle("");

                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + mainFolder + "/" + timeTableFolder);
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    f.mkdirs();
                }

                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(mainFolder + "/" + timeTableFolder, nameOfFile);

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Of nameOfFile replace .aspx by  .pdf.

Comment: like nameOfFile.replace(".aspx",".pdf")